# RegEx Model Validation: Whole Number or Decimal Multiples of .25

Tags: c#, regex, entity-framework, attributes, data-annotations

I am trying to compose a regular expression to match a numeric value expressed as a decimal multiple of `.25` (ex. `1.25`, `14.75`).

```
// Must Match
1.0
1.25
1.250000
1.5
1.500
1.75
1.7500

// Must Not Match
1.2
1.46
1.501
1.99
```

So far I have the following expression: `\d+(\.((0+)|(250*)|(50*)|(750*)))`. It works when I use online tooling like [gskinner.com/regexr](http://gskinner.com/regexr). When I use the expression in a validation attribute to seed my EntityFramework db, it produces validation errors:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d+(\.((0+)|(250*)|(50*)|(750*)))$", ErrorMessage = "Hours must be 15 minute increments expressed as decimals (ex. .0, .25, .5, .75)")]
public double Hours { get; set; }
```

Similar question ([I am looking for a way to round the decimal portion of numbers up or down to the nearest .25, .5, .75, or whole number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900572/i-am-looking-for-a-way-to-round-the-decimal-portion-of-numbers-up-or-down-to-the)) but I need to use a regular expression to use the above data annotation.

#### Question:

1. Anyone see what's wrong with my expression?
2. Bonus points if you can extend it to support whole numbers (ex. `4` or `4.25` but not `4.` or `4.62`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **match** such number use regex pattern

```
 (?!0\d)\d+(?:[.](?:25|5|75|0)0*)?(?!\d)
```

To **validate** input to be such number use regex pattern

```
 ^(?!0\d)\d+(?:[.](?:25|5|75|0)0*)?$
```

---

In both cases, the very first part `(?!0\d)` is optional to disallow match/validate numbers with invalid leading zeros, such as `000003.250`, when match would trim them and take just `3.250`; validation would fail if this optional part is present in the regex.

Comment: Two questions... (1) does wrapping the period character in brackets effectively escape it (ex. `[.]` = `\.`)? (2) I understand the usage of `^` and `$` to start and end the expression but did you mean to leave out the trailing third group `(?!\d)` in the validation example? If it was intentional, why is it unnecessary there?

Comment: @one.beat.consumer - **Re(1):** yes, `[.]` is same as `\.`, as period does not have to be escaped within set `[]`; **Re(2):** Negative lookahead `(?!\d)` prevents other unwanted digit to be behind the match, such as `4` in `12.750004`, as without such condition you would get match `12.75000`.

Comment: I thought so, then it should probably be included in the validation string, no? `4.250009` should fail.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer - For validation, you have `$` at the end of the pattern and that says **absolutely nothing** is behind, so then it is not needed. If you have input such as `It costs 12.750 USD`, then you need to use matching pattern, if your input is just such number: `12.750`, then you need to use validation pattern. I don't know what you are working with... Tell us what you are doing.

Comment: Your last sentence cleared everything up. As you see in the question it is a `double` property - the validation pattern is most appropriate. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This matches whole numbers too:

```
^\d+(\.(25|5|75|0)0*)?$
```

I tested it with [RegexHero](http://regexhero.net/tester/). It has a .NET Regex engine in the backstage. If you're using all test cases together, make sure that you make `Multiline` option selected, so that `^` and `$` symbols match each line individually, not the whole text.

Comment: Why do you have grouping parentheses around each piece of the alternation?